# Converting an iterator into a stream and calling parallel, is the conversion done on shared thread pool threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, java-stream, guava

So I'm using the Guava's library Streams.stream(iterator) method to convert an iterator into a stream. And then I call parallel on that stream and perform some operations.

What I'm wonder is whether the converting of the iterator into a stream is done on the shared thread pool threads or beforehand.

```
        Stream<MyItem> myItemStream = Streams.stream(myItemIterator);
        myItem.parallel()...
```

Wondering because if the iterator conversion is done on the shared thread pool threads, that poses a problem for my use case in terms of thread safety.

Thanks!

Comment: I would look for the implementation of `Spliterator.trySplit`. That will tell you how they implement parallelism. [The implementation from OpenJDK, for example, puts the elements in an array.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Spliterators.java#l1753)

Comment: An `Iterator` is not thread safe and hence, the Stream implementation will never access your `Iterator` from different threads. On the other hand, since it also has no active support for parallel processing, parallel processing can only be done by buffering elements before handing them over to another thread (and the iterator doesn’t even suggest the number of elements), so you need a really large number of elements and have to chain heavy computations, to see a positive effect from parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Streams.stream(Iterator)` is just a convenience method around a call to the java `StreamSupport` class:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
  return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
}
```

As such the Stream will use the common ForkJoinPool.